# gnome-online-accounts (GOA) with Xubuntu?

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, 15.10, xfce, online-accounts

1) Is there some alternative to gnome-online-accounts (GOA) for use in Xubuntu?

2) If I install gnome-online-accounts in Xubuntu it pulls in the following dependencies

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apg cracklib-runtime cups-pk-helper dconf-cli dleyna-server gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gkbd-capplet
  gnome-bluetooth gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center-shared-data
  gnome-online-accounts gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-user-share ibus
  libcanberra-pulse libcheese-gtk23 libcolord-gtk1 libcrack2 libdleyna-connector-dbus-1.0-1
  libdleyna-core-1.0-3 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 libgoa-backend-1.0-1
  libgupnp-av-1.0-2 libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 libibus-1.0-5 libpwquality-common libpwquality1
  libtelepathy-glib0 libwacom-bin libwacom-common libwacom2 mousetweaks nautilus-data realmd
  ubuntu-system-service
```

It doesn't look fun and my question is if you can foresee any problems with having these dependencies installed in Xubuntu (15.10)?

Comment: If you find a solution, can you post that as an *answer* instead of in the question?

Comment: OK, done, new to AskUbuntu...

Answer (score 17):

Took the plunge and installed the gnome-online-accounts. No adverse effects seen yet.

In order to use GOA you need to start gnome-control-center as follows:

```
$ env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center
```

to trick the desktop to believe it is running GNOME. Worked fine after that and provided Evolution in my case the right authentications for Gmail/Calender etc.

Comment: There is really a superb instruction for GOA on Xubuntu on youtube: https://youtu.be/Px_1cZZPE-Y

Comment: As an advice, turn off the calendar option if you are getting 100% ram spikes. Kill `indicator-datetime` first.